# Add target=" _parent" to <form> tag on WordPress Contact form 7?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, iframe, contacts

I am creating a form that will be iframed into another site. I would like the re-direct to a 'thank you' page to be done on the parent page on submit.

Is there a way I can add the target="_parent" attribute to my form tag in Contact Form 7?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the AJAX version (default) of Contact Form 7, then you can subscribe to the `wpcf7mailsent` custom event that is triggered on completion, then set the URL of the `top` frame. For example:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    window.top.location = 'http://example.com/thank-you/';
    // Or if the parent window is not the top window, you can use
    // window.parent.location = 'http://example.com/thank-you/';
}, false );
</script>
```

Official docs: https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/

**Edit:**
You can make additional decisions within the callback based on the values stored in the `event` argument object. For example, to redirect only in the case of a specific form:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if (event.detail.contactFormId == 12) {
        window.top.location = 'http://example.com/thank-you/';
    }
}, false );
```

Source: https://contactform7.com/dom-events/

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has worked. I was not able to add this to the 'additional settings' box on CF7, instead I added this to the <head> of the theme header PHP file.

It's now targetting every form on the site. Is there a way I can target a specific form?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!